# Update Validators in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem updating the values of `car_description`.
Initially, the `car_description` is set to required.
But if `value.car_description` isn't null then I need to patch its value from the `onSelectPlateNo()`.
and it should be disabled so you can't change it.

My problem now is that I can't submit it, since it is still required even though the values are already set.

```
this.serviceTransactionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    car_description: [null, Validators.required],
});



onSelectPlateNo(value) {
    if (value.car_description) {
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').clearValidators();
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').setValidators(null);
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').updateValueAndValidity();
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').disable();
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').setValue(value.car_description);
    } else {
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').enable();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formControl can either be

- VALID
- INVALID
- DISABLED
- PENDING

By

```
this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').disable();
```

you're setting the status of this form field to `DISABLED`. The values of

```
this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').valid
```

and

```
this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').invalid
```

are both false.

Two possible solutions are:

1. Negate the check: Instead of

   ```
   if (this.serviceTransactionForm.valid)
   ```

   check for

   ```
   if (!this.serviceTransactionForm.invalid)
   ```
2. Use `readOnly` instead of `disabled` in the HTML template

   ```
   <input type="text" formControlName="car_description" [readonly]="car_description_read_only">
   ```

You can reduce your code to

```
this.serviceTransactionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    car_description: [null, Validators.required],
});

car_description_read_only = false;

onSelectPlateNo(value) {
    if (value.car_description) {
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').setValue(value.car_description);
      this.car_description_read_only = true;
    } else {
      this.serviceTransactionForm.get('car_description').enable();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm thinking of readOnly too but how can you set it to that?

Comment: @Joseph I added an example for `readonly`. You need a variable for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeControl.
Example in your case:
this.serviceTransactionForm.removeControl('car_description')

Comment: This causes that the user can change the value and get error messages in the log: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ddvfsn?file=src/app/app.component.ts Also OP wants to submit the whole form.